# Sending Mail in Python - Error code - SMTPDataError: 451, b 4.3.0 Mail server temporarily rejected message

Tags: python-3.x, email, gmail

I am able to send mail without issue when I implement the same code very plain without using any functions. But when I try to send mail using a function I am getting mail as my senders account is disabled and it is blocking my mail and account.

Have to implement a code for sending mails after certain filters are met in a function so that it can be used to send mail whenever wanted.

My code snippet:

```
import smtplib

def setup_mail():
    global smtpObj,sender,receivers,message
    sender = 'sample@gmail.com'
    receivers = ['sample1@gmail.com','sample2@gmail.com']

    message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
    To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
    Subject: 1 MIN candle 15 points alert
    
    TIME: watch out next 2 minutes
    """

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    smtpObj.login("sample@gmail.com","samplepassword")
setup_mail()
def sending_mails(smtpObj):
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
for i in range(3):
    sending_mails(smtpObj);
print("Successfully sent email")
```

The error i got,

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/Arun/PycharmProjects/Astro/venv/Scripts/ZERODHA_DEV/sendmail.py", line 22, in  sending_mails(smtpObj); File "C:/Users/Arun/PycharmProjects/Astro/venv/Scripts/ZERODHA_DEV/sendmail.py", line 20, in sending_mails smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message) File "C:\Python\lib\smtplib.py", line 888, in sendmail raise SMTPDataError(code, resp) smtplib.SMTPDataError: (451, b'4.3.0 Mail server temporarily rejected message. s77sm14888153pfc.164 - gsmtp')

However it works with a simple code like,

```
import smtplib

global smtpObj,sender,receivers,message
sender = 'sample@gmail.com'
receivers = ['sample1@gmail.com','sample2@gmail.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: 1 MIN candle 15 points alert

TIME: watch out next 2 minutes
"""

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
smtpObj.login("sample@gmail.com","samplepassword")
for i in range(3):
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
   print("Successfully sent email")
```

Comment: Below is the error i got,Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Arun/PycharmProjects/Astro/venv/Scripts/ZERODHA_DEV/sendmail.py", line 22, in <module>
    sending_mails(smtpObj);
  File "C:/Users/Arun/PycharmProjects/Astro/venv/Scripts/ZERODHA_DEV/sendmail.py", line 20, in sending_mails
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
  File "C:\Python\lib\smtplib.py", line 888, in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (451, b'4.3.0 Mail server temporarily rejected message. s77sm14888153pfc.164 - gsmtp')

Comment: And  i missed to mention, i have already enabled access for third party and captcha in Gmail setting and location as well

Comment: Are you sure you're not just hitting sending limits? Your question doesn't otherwise make much sense, how would the SMTP server know you're using a function

Comment: Yes, no sending limit reached. When i run this program, it disables my account after sending mail once. So it blocks when it tries to send 2nd time. And i found a stackoverflow page where same issue is faced, but no one suggested solution as well,weird

Comment: Normally that kind of a limitation comes with free service. If you want something more professional, you'll typically have to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that your message is indented; a valid SMTP message contains two literal adjacent newlines to demarcate the headers from the body.

While you can assemble simple email messages from ASCII strings, this is not tenable for real-world modern email messages. You *really* want to use the `email` library (or a higher level third-party wrapper or replacement) to handle all the corner cases of email message encapsulation, *especially* if you are not an expert on email and MIME yourself.

Comment: I'd show example code but this is a common FAQ; refer to some of my other recent answers in the [tag:python] [tag:email] tags for concrete examples.